# Access to java list of object and with js or extjs

Tags: java, javascript, list, extjs

I want to work on a list of object with javascript (i can use extjs too in my project). You can see that I have two list in my jsp (modelList and categoryList) forwarded by my controller. and I want to access data into my two list. Is it possible ?

my jsp :

```
<table class="form">
    <tr>
        <td class="label"><a class="required"></a><spring:message code="serviceModel.category" /></td>
        <td class="value">
                <form:select path="category" onchange="javascript:App.reloadUserNumberOnCategoryChangeForWorkflow(this, ${categoryList}, ${modelList}) ;App.removeError(this)>
                    <form:option label="" value="" />
                    <form:options items="${categoryList}" itemLabel="description" itemValue="description" />
                </form:select>
                <form:errors path="category" cssClass="errormsg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label"><a class="required"></a><spring:message code="service.userNumber" /></td>
        <td class="value">
                <form:select path="userNumber">
                    <form:option label="" value="" />
                    <form:options items="${modelList}" itemLabel="description" itemValue="description" />
                </form:select>
                <form:errors path="userNumber" cssClass="errormsg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

my controller :

```
uiModel.addAttribute(WebConstants.CATEGORY_LIST, catList);
uiModel.addAttribute(WebConstants.MODEL_LIST, modelList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a JSON service that turned your java object into a JSON array, and then retrieve that list from the server with an AJAX call.

Spring, Struts, etc. have built in ways to do this, or you could roll your own with a good 'ol servlet and a JSON library (you should be able to find one at json.org).

Comment: I already had a jsonController to do that but I was not sure if there if another way. But I think it's the best way. thank you

Comment: In the past I have rolled my own solution by creating a custom code Tag (implementing TagSupport) that would spit out a javascript block declaring a javascript var, and generating the JSON to represent the object you pass in.  It does work real nice when you have a smaller object you wish to access in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, no.

The only way this would be possible would be by using the View to write JavaScript code that would define the object.

In your case, it would be something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <c:if test="${not empty modelList}">
    var modelList = [
      <c:forEach var="model" items="${modelList}">
        {
            description: '<c:out value="${model.description}"/>',
            otherProperty: '<c:out value="${model.otherProperty}">'
        },
      </c:forEach>
    ]
  </c:if>
</script>
```